# Getting 304 response using Core 3.1 HttpClient.SendAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I posst JSON to a vendor's server using HttpClient.SendAsync() under .Net Framework 4.6.1 and get a valid response with no problem. However, when I try the same code under Core 3.1.2, I get an HTTP Status Code of 304 (Not Modified) on the first attempt, but get a good response on the second attempt. What changed with Core? Any suggestions on how to work around this?

```
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJson(string uri, string userName, string password, object content)
    {
        using var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        AddBasicAuthorizationHeader(userName, password, httpRequestMessage);
        httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: Have you compared exactly what headers/values are being sent with the requests between each versions?

Answer (score 0):

304 Is mostly to ensure that there is minimized information transfer in case of the client already having same representation of information as on server. 304  usually ends with only headers, as mentioned in other answer I would also suggest to look at the headers of both the request , the one which gives 304 and the one which gives 200 OK and also you might need to understand if there is a specific period for which the class after 304 will succeed with 200 OK or every alternative call to server is 304 and then a 200 OK followed by that. and if it is possible please post the header comparison.